# Compare team names of different bookmakers

Tags: string, compare, names

I am trying to make a small sport betting odds comparison script for my personal use. For this I am getting the data of the XML feeds (from the different bookmakers). For comparing them I have to know which matches/events are exactly the same.
The problem is that the name of teams, leagues are often different at different bookmakers.

Here an example:

---

Bookmaker1: B1

League: UEFA Champions League

Match: Manchester United vs Inter Milan

---

Bookmaker2: B2

League: Champions L.

Match: Manu vs Inter

---

Bookmaker3: B3

League: Champions League(UEFA)

Match: Manchester U. vs    FC Internazionale

---

The date will be the same. But there are a lot of matches starting at the same time. There are 1000's of matches and 100's of leagues.

Is there another possibility to recognize that they are same, than do it manually?

With manually I mean: if string is Manu or Manchester U. => Manchester United
(and this for every teamname)

How odds comparison sites do this (like oddsportal.com or other services)?

Comment: @Grant I am using php and curl to get the data. I know some string comparing functions, but using them is what I mean with check it manually. :) Because I have to check every kind of teamname or not?

Answer (score 3):

Very old question but, perhaps other users could benefit.
Sorry, about my bad English. I try to explain.
I'm C# developer, so I just explain how you can do that.

If you make your own teams dictionary, you can handle this problem.

1. Make your own SoccerTeams table on your database. In this case, MongoDb or any documentDb best solution for you. It can also be relational database, no problem.
2. Bookmakers1, Bookmakers2 or more no different. Just check your own database for team names. For examle :

   Bookmaker1 Home Team Name : Manchester United

   Bookmaker1 Away Team Name : Inter Milan

   Bookmaker2 Home Team Name : Manchester Utd.

   Bookmaker2 Away Team Name : Inter
3. In this case we must check string similarity and we could use "Levanstein Distance" or similar algorithms for this. Here is some algorithms [Url](https://medium.com/@appaloosastore/string-similarity-algorithms-compared-3f7b4d12f0ff).
4. Firstly get teams from database. And check teams similarity with loop.
   If distance is closer for example, "Manchester United vs Manchester Utd" distance bigger than %50. You can add this Different table name of like "SimilaritySoccerTeamNames".
   And after all, you have similarity table like that :

```css
table.myTable tr th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table class="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th width="100px">Id</th>
      <th width="200px">Name</th>
      <th width="200px">SimilarName</th>
      <th width="100px">Distance</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Manchester United</td>
      <td>Manchester Utd</td>
      <td>70</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Manchester United</td>
      <td>Manchester City</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Manchester United</td>
      <td>Manu</td>
      <td>20</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Inter Milan</td>
      <td>Inter</td>
      <td>45</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>Beşiktaş JK</td>
      <td>Beşiktaş AŞ</td>
      <td>75</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>Besiktas</td>
      <td>Beşiktaş</td>
      <td>63</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

So, you can select and combine these teams manually. You must carefull about your codes. Gent vs Genk similarity also %99 percentage. And these are different teams. You must manually. And you can improve this solution. For example, if 2 game of bookmakers same dates and home teams match and away team name similarity bigger than %50, you can add automatically. And after all, you can make easier all this jobs and save your time. I just explain how you can do that. Also you can improve this solution. Just I wanted to explain logic. You can make better. If you want any help, I'm here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there is no magical solution. I don't see any pattern you can base on.

The best way is to identify the name used for each bookmaker and do the comparison accordingly.

It is unlikely that bookmakers will change the team's name

Answer (score 0):

As the same teams, playing the same day, you can connect a name of team, and check this team on the same date, the opposite team, and connect these teams.
A team cannot play the same day with another team.
By this way you can map all the teams by one.